# Permissão para pasta /var/www/html

Tags: ubuntu

Instalei o Apache, Mysql e PHP. Porém quando vou tentar criar o phpinfo para testar o PHP na pasta, dá permissão negada.

Já acessei como root e executei o `chmod 777`. mas continua a dar 'permissão negada'

Comment: Quem dá "permissão negada"? Na hora de criar o arquivo ou na hora de executar?

Comment: Na hora de gravar o arquivo.

Comment: A resposta que dei foi pensando que você estava no ambiente de desenvolvimento. Não faça isso em produção. Fiz até uma pergunta para a gente tirar melhor essas dúvidas. [Quais são os riscos de usar permissão 777?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/169996/quais-s%C3%A3o-os-riscos-de-usar-permiss%C3%A3o-777)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sempre que eu tenho um problema de leitura de arquivos, eu utilizo o comando `sudo chmod` com a opção `-R`.

Veja:

```
cd /var/www/html
sudo chmod -R 777 .
```

Nesse caso, você está dizendo para ele fazer isso recursivamente (a opção `-R`), pegando todo o diretório.

Lembrando que eu estou supondo que você esteja aplicando tal operação na sua própria máquina. Em servidores cujo o ambiente é em produção não recomendo dar permissão total a uma pasta.

Comment: Funcionou!! Muito Obrigado!!

Comment: É no ambiente local. Obrigado!