# Quais são os riscos de usar permissão 777?

Tags: segurança, sistema-de-arquivos

Sempre quando tenho problema de permissões de pastas no meu sistema operacional Ubuntu, eu costumo dar a permissão `777` para a determinada pasta. Costumo fazer isso no ambiente de desenvolvimento.

Em algumas situações, já dei esse tipo de permissão em ambiente de produção em um servidor Linux, onde rodo minhas aplicações escritas em PHP.

Por exemplo, 
quando tive um problema específico de escrita de arquivos de upload na pasta `public/uploads` de um determinado sistema, eu dei a permissão `777` nesta pasta.

Porém vejo sempre recomendações de que devemos usar a permissão `755` ou `644`, porque usar `777` é perigoso.

Mas em que sentido isso seria perigoso?

Por que os programadores mais experientes sempre recomendam a utilização de outros valores para permissões de pasta em produção ao invés de `777`?

Por exemplo, já ouvi dizer que uma pessoa pode ter problemas com ataques a uma aplicação web caso haja uma permissão de escrita `777` em determinada pasta. Isso é verdade?

Seria legal também se a resposta pudesse explicar melhor sobre as diferenças entre `644`, `755` e `777`.

Comment: Resposta que fala sobre o tema: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2281/67

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Permissão negada ao mover arquivo com move\_upload\_file em servidor Linux](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2270/permiss%c3%a3o-negada-ao-mover-arquivo-com-move-upload-file-em-servidor-linux)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Ao dar permissões `777` para um arquivo você faz com que todos os usuários possam ler, escrever e executar o mesmo.

Isso significa que qualquer vulnerabilidade do seu sistema permite que um invasor faça o que bem entender com esse arquivo. Pior ainda, com a combinação de permissões de escrita e leitura, um atacante com conhecimento suficiente sobre o seu sistema pode fazer com que um outro usuário privilegiado execute algo sem saber.

---

### Um exemplo ilustrativo

Bob é o *sysadmin* responsável por um servidor JBoss. O JBoss de Bob está rodando com o usuário `jboss`. Sua aplicação tem um *script* inofensivo que copia arquivos de uma pasta de negócios `upload` para uma pasta de contexto do apache (usuário `apache`) otimizada para servir arquivos estáticos; esse *script* roda com o usuário `jboss`. Soa como algo que você vê por aí não? Por exemplo, para *upload* de avatares e coisas do gênero.

Digamos que Bob, não querendo lutar com permissões de acesso entre o `jboss` e `apache` foi lá e executou `chmod 777` na pasta de contexto do Apache. Com isso o *script* em questão, mesmo rodando com o usuário do `jboss`, pode escrever arquivos na pasta do apache sem ser incomodado. Parece inofensivo certo?

Depois Bob começou a ter problemas ao lidar com esses arquivos do usuário `jboss` dentro de uma pasta que pertence ao `apache`. O apache não exibia as imagens copiadas pelo *script*. Bob, com pressa, foi lá e alterou seu *script* para rodar um `chmod 777` em todos os arquivos que estão sendo copiados para a pasta do apache. Bob não viu nenhum risco em fazer isso já que a aplicação da firma tinha uma função JavaScript que validava a extensão dos arquivos que eram enviados pelos usuários. A aplicação só permitia que arquivos com extensões de imagem fossem enviadas para o servidor. Alice, a desenvolvedora da firma, copiou a função JavaScript [desse post do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4237161/664577) e colou na aplicação web em questão.

Mallory verifica então que o PHP está instalado no Apache; rodando inclusive na pasta de imagens estáticas... De novo Bob não viu necessidade de ficar mexendo com arquivos de configuração do Apache já que a pasta em questão só teria imagens mesmo.

Mallory então:

1. Abre as ferramentas de desenvolvimento do Chrome e modifica a função de validação de Alice para permitir *upload* de arquivos `.php`.
2. Cria um *script* PHP qualquer, por exemplo, para apagar ou roubar todas as imagens do servidor de Bob.
3. Faz *upload* do arquivo pelo Chrome
4. Espera o *script* do Bob rodar
5. Executa o *script* PHP através da pasta de contexto do Apache.

O usuário `apache` está agora executando o *script* de Mallory. Mallory acabou de ganhar acesso ao Apache através de uma vulnerabilidade em uma aplicação rodando no JBoss.

Generalizando os pontos da história:

1. Resolver um problema usando `chmod 777` geralmente cria outros problemas que chamam por `chmod 777` (permissões estão lá por um motivo)
2. `chmod 777` dá acesso a escrita e execução de um arquivo. Essa combinação abre portas para vários tipos de *exploits*
3. `chmod 777` significa que seu arquivo poderá ser lido, escrito e executado por qualquer usuário. Isso significa que qualquer usuário que seja comprometido vai poder fazer o que quiser com o arquivo / pasta.
4. Componentes de software interagem de formas não triviais e falhas de segurança vão sendo acumuladas através das camadas (Alice não validou arquivos no *server-side* da sua aplicação, Bob não desativou o PHP na pasta de contexto do Apache e ainda escreveu um *script* péssimo). Por mais que você confie nas suas aplicações, é importante manter segurança em todas as camadas e isso inclui as permissões do sistema de arquivos.

Answer (score 41):

### TL;DR;

Dar permissão 777 é o mesmo que :

- "Confiar em todo mundo, independente de quem seja".
- "Permitir que qualquer um faça o que quiser".

Você "confia" que ninguém, **absolutamente ninguém**, vai fazer nada que você não queira e todos seguiram as regras. - (É por isso que não nos preocupamos com segurança não é mesmo?)

#### Porque 777, e não 7 ou 77

O sistema de permissão se baseia em três níveis de acesso.

- Dono - Usuário logado que criou a pasta/arquivo.
- Grupo - Grupo em que o usuário esta inserido (analogia para família).
- 3º - Outros usuários, que não fazem parte do seu grupo (analogia para estrangeiro).

Horizontalmente escrito assim :

`Dono | Grupo | 3º`

#### E porque 7?

O sistema de permissão também se baseia em três ações.

- r - Ler
- w - Escrever
- x - Executar

As combinações possíveis geram uma tabela assim :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Logo pode se ver que 7 seria permissão geral, **RWX**

#### Acesso + Ações

Assim podemos definir exatamente quem e o que pode ser feito no arquivo/pasta.

- 7 - Eu sou o dono, posso fazer o que quiser.
- 5 - Você é da minha família, mas só vou deixar `ler` e `executar`, não quero que edite nada.
- 0 - Você é estrangeiro não confio você, não quero nem sequer que possa ler, vai que roube minha ideia.

#### Por que as pessoa geralmente usam 777

A resposta para isso esta no acesso, pois o dono do arquivo é um usuário "comum" e o apache é um usuário "avançado" responsável por gerir o servidor. E eles sequer estão no mesmo grupo `utilizadores`, `rede`.

Ou seja quando eu estou dando permissão para um arquivo/pasta que criei o apache sera o 3º (estrangeiro).

As pessoas em um modo simples pensam, "ah é o apache que vai acessar" e usam 7, mas esquecem que isso vale para qualquer outra pessoa. inclusive as mal intencionadas.

### Adendo

Em servidores isso é mais difícil de acontecer, mas é possível alterar o dono do arquivo/pasta, ou mesmo por os dois no mesmo grupo, assim você poderia restringir os acessos.

#### Alterando dono

- Eu criei a pasta, mas quem vai alterar e escrever é o apache então para não usar `777`.
- Eu digo que o apache é o novo dono. `chown apache file`.
- Como usuário apache altero a permissão para `700`.

#### Integrando o mesmo grupo

- Eu e apache estamos no mesmo grupo.
- Então o só preciso trabalhar com 2 bits e manter o terceiro sempre em 0.
- `770` - Eu e meu grupo podemos fazer o que queremos, o 3º não tem acesso a nada.

Comment: Ali não é gravar e sim escrever. De resto, excelente explicação.

Comment: @JorgeB. Eu sempre achei como gravar, mas realmente faz mais sentido, vou editar.

Comment: Guilherme é r de read, w de write e x execute ;)

Comment: É traduzindo literalmente.

Comment: Guilherme mas neste caso é mesmo escrever, quando gravas, o que acontece é que estás a escrever no ficheiro. Por isso é que se diz escrever no ficheiro e também permissão de escrita.

Answer (score 2):

Como foi dito acima, usar permissão 777 não é uma boa escolha, pois você permite que todos leia, escrevam e executem.

Permissões usando chmod com numeros é muito complicado utilize a tabela de letras com as opções + e - como foi apresentado acima.

Outra opção é que ninguém citou que é recomendada executar junto com **chmod** é utilizar o comando **chown** (o chown altera o dono do arquivo e enquanto o chmod altera as permissões)

Só passei para dar uma reforçada. :)

Answer (score 2):

> Por exemplo, quando tive um problema específico de escrita de arquivos
>   de upload na pasta public/uploads de um determinado sistema, eu dei a
>   permissão 777 nesta pasta.

Adoro quem vive de modo perigoso rsrs(brincadeira), já está mais do que explicado os motivos, as respostas anteriores falaram tudo, só vim aqui acrescentar com exemplos práticos o que pode acontecer, de como o seu Sistema Operacional pode ser invadido...

Imagine que estou andando na sua página e me deparo em uma área de upload, digamos que o algoritmo de upload não checa metadados e nem extensões de arquivos, você simplesmente vai estar perdido, o atacante não vai ter acesso root, mas mesmo assim pode fazer um bom estrago, certamente ele vai conseguir ler muitas coisas dentro do seu `SO`, além de conseguir olhar os códigos fontes de sua página (php, asp, etc), pode até conseguir as senhas do seu banco de dados para acesso (olhando os códigos da sua página ele pode achar as senhas de conexão do seu banco), neste caso o atacante não precisa ser muito esperto, ele iria subir um arquivo na pasta pasta upload ex. `hack.php`(um código que abra arquivos e mostre na tela), depois é só executar e ver o retorno...

```
http://meusite/upload/hack.php?var=/etc/passwd
```

Se ele for um pouco mais esperto, faria um arquivo .php que envie e retorne comandos `(dir, ls, rm)`

```
http://meusite/upload/comandos.php?var=ls&local=/etc/
```

Claro estou só falando coisas básicas para não dar idéias para os mal intencionados, isso é crítico, é o pior cenário possível, o hacker poderia subir qualquer arquivo e usar o php, asp, java, python, etc para executar, poderia tentar escalar root utilizando exploits e ter controle total do SO, ou seja seria uma "festa" dentro da sua pasta upload :-(

Agora imagine que o seu algoritmo de upload check extensões, mas não olha metadados (cabeçalhos), vamos imaginar que o seu algorítimo em tese só deixe fazer upload arquivos `.jpg`, imagine que eu crie o seguinte arquivo:

```
<?php echo "<p>Ola Mundo</p>"; ?>
```

E salve como `teste.jpg`(claro é um exemplo bobo, mas poderia ser algo realmente perigoso), sua pasta upload viraria um campo minado, códigos maliciosos dentro de extensões permitidas :-( digo que é um campo minado pois o hacker só vai precisar disparar o gatilho, geralmente esse gatilho não pode ser executado de fora, via `http`, eu disse "geralmente", o hacker vai precisar usar artifícios para executar por exemplo um  `php teste.jpg`.

Esse são só exemplos superficiais de como uma pasta de upload com `chmod 777` pode se tornar o calcanhar de aquiles do seu `SO`.