# Upload de imagem no servidor não funciona

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Quando faço o upload localmente, utilizando o WAMP64, tudo ocorre normalmente. Porém, quando vou fazer o upload pelo site, que está no servidor de produção, é apresentado a seguinte mensagem de erro.

> NoWritableException in Image.php line 143:
>
> Can't write image data to path (/home/premiumcarstudio/laravel/public/1481746280.jpeg)

[image: Can't write image data to path]

**Código que estou tentando utilizar para upload**

```
if ($request->hasFile('fileUpload')) {
        $image = $request->file('fileUpload');
        $filename  = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $path = public_path('images/ImagensPosts/' . $filename);
        Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(570,350)->save(public_path($filename));
        $post->imagem = 'images/ImagensPosts/'.$filename;
    }
    
    $post->save();
```

**OBS.**
Já fiz a alteração das permissões de acesso ao diretório de imagens no servidor.

**Diretório no Servidor**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Botão direito em cima da pasta public no FTP, Permissões, e seleciona as opções gravar no meio.

Comment: [Manual de como não fazer perguntas](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485)

Comment: Creio que isso seja problema de permissão, como o Gumball falou. Talvez você queria dar uma olhada em [Quais os riscos de usar a permissão 777](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/169996/quais-s%C3%A3o-os-riscos-de-usar-permiss%C3%A3o-777)

Answer (score 1):

No [Laravel 5.3](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests#storing-uploaded-files), o padrão recomendado é salvar na pasta storage/app, que já possui permissão para escrita. Geralmente eu uso:

```
$request->nome_do_campo_do_arquivo->storeAs('pasta_de_destino', 'nome_do_arquivo.ext')
```

Isso cria a pasta de destino (caso não exista) e dá um novo nome para o arquivo.

Caso esteja usando versões anteriores, tente dar permissão de escrita na pasta public/. Espero ter ajudado.

Para ver a documentação, [clique aqui](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests#storing-uploaded-files).

Comment: Consegui fazer o upload dessa imagem no servidor através do seu comando, mas não consegui exibir a imagem, poderia me passar como esta sua tag <img>... tentei colocar os caminhos até mesmo localhost e a imagem não é encontrada... obrigado

Comment: Situação resolvida com essa resposta